# Cake eating problem

Tags: macroeconomics, dynamic-programming

Consider an infinitely lived agent born in time zero, endowed with a cake of size $x_0$. The cake is storable (without depreciation) and infinitely divisible. The agent derives contemporary utility from (cake) consumption through $u(c_t)$, and as usual, maximizes his infinitely discounted sum of utility streams. The discount rate is, as usual, given by β.

My guess is that the sequence problem to this is: $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \beta^tu(c_t)$ s.t $c_t + x_{t+1} ≤ x_t$;

$x_{t+1}≥0$ is the amount of cake left at the end of the current period ;

$c_t≥0$

But I feel like I'm missing something in the constraints.

Comment: The constraints: (1) $c_t \geq 0$, (2) $c_t + x_{t+1} = x_t$ and (3) $x_0$ given, are all you need.

Comment: @WalrasianAuctioneer I see, thank you for the clarification.